# Best approach to update SELECT OPTION values using PHP/Javascript by communicating with database

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a page where user can enter a product details. There are two Categories, Main and Sub. the main category contains parents value for example "car" and the subcategory contains values related to main category for example "Ferrari". there are about 15 main category choices and 100s of subcategory choices.

I would like to be able to select the parent category "motorbike" and have the sub category automatically update its value to meets the motorbike sub category such as "Yamaha R1" instead of having sub categories that are not related to "motorbike" such as "PS4".

All categories values are stored to the database.

In order for me to do that I believe I need to get the user input value from the main category, using Javascript, send that to PHP using Ajax, PHP does a sql query such as (SELECT DISTINCT sub-cat from PRODUCT where MainCAt = "CAR"); get whatever value is returned, send that value back to javascript and then I will be able to alter the sub category values.

However I am stuck, I dont know if php is getting the Main category values. And even if it is I dont know what to do next.
Any advice would be much appreciated.

Also you are welcome to change title as I couldnt find a better one.

HTML:

```
<select name="Cat" id="Cat" onchange="subCatActivation()">
    <option value="BlanketsAndTowels">Blankets And Towels</option>
    <option value="Candles" onclick="">Candles</option>
    <option value="Cards">Cards</option>
    <option value="Children">Children</option>
    <option value="Christmas">Christmas</option>
    <option value="Cushions">Cushions</option>
    <option value="Frames">Frames</option>
    <option value="Hand-Made">Hand-Made</option>
    <option value="Lanterns">Lanterns</option>
    <option value="Outside">Outside</option>
    <option value="Soaps">Soaps</option>
    <option value="Vintages">Vintages</option>
</select>
```

JAVACRIPT:

```
function subCatActivation(){
    var selectedBox = document.getElementById("Cat");
    var val = selectedBox.options[selectedBox.selectedIndex].value;
    var httpRequest;
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if(!httpRequest){
        return false;
    }
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && httpRequest.status === 200)
        {
            var response = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
        }
    }
    httpRequest.open('POST', 'index.php');
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    httpRequest.send('catVal=' + val);

    updateLayout();

}
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['catVal'])){
    echo "test";
    exit();
}
```

Comment: you can use console.log() or alert() to see if the initial selected value is being updated properly, but it kind of looks like you're using index.php as the url for your ajax request. should we assume that's just to hide the real one or is that real?

Comment: its nto the real name but everything there is written inside this file.